# Using PyDBG how to find in which loaded module callee functions is present

Tags: debuggers, debugging, python

Is there any quick/ faster way to find , any address resides in which loaded module.

For example from stack if I have ret address of any api. I want to check from which module actually that function was get called ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from pydbg import *
from pydbg.defines import *

def handler_breakpoint (pydbg):   
   if pydbg.first_breakpoint:
    dbg.bp_set(dbg.func_resolve("user32","SendMessageW"))
    return DBG_CONTINUE
   retaddr = dbg.get_arg(0,dbg.context)
   modname = dbg.addr_to_module(retaddr).szModule   
   print "Calling Module and Return Address %25s\t%08x" % (modname,retaddr)
   return DBG_CONTINUE

dbg = pydbg()
dbg.set_callback(EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT, handler_breakpoint)
dbg.load("c:\windows\system32\calc.exe")
pydbg.debug_event_loop(dbg)
```

result

```
Calling Module and Return Address              comctl32.dll     773f2883
Calling Module and Return Address              comctl32.dll     773f2883
Calling Module and Return Address                USER32.dll     7e4269ed
Calling Module and Return Address                USER32.dll     7e4269fa
```